# WebClient DownloadFile Error , Illegal characters in path

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following Code to download image from url

```
using (WebClient Client = new WebClient())
{
    Random rand = new Random();
    int r = rand.Next(9999999);
    string filepath = @"d:\images\"+ r.ToString() +"_"+ reader.GetValue(2).ToString() +".jpg";
    Client.DownloadFile(reader.GetString(0), filepath);
}
```

the resulted path will be "d:\images\6195111_178.jpg" in filepath variable 
The error saying "Illegal characters in path"

Comment: And why do you use a local path?

Comment: It will be interesting to know the value returned by reader.GetString(0)

Comment: @Steve Its a file to be downloaded , and the path should have extenstion

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer , I replace the downloaded file path by another  and it works , seems the function looking for a file with extention in the path